# Error occurring when reading CSV (tab delimited) file created by Python to R

Tags: r, python-3.x

I am currently trying to analyze Twitter data collected via Python which is saved as tab delimited CSV file. However, a problem occurs when I try to read it into R. 
The data is comprised of 8 columns (e.g.,col1: Twitter ID, col2: date of tweets, ... col4: tweet messages.. col9: location information).

So I expecting each row to contain information of those eight columns for all data points. However, for some reason in col4 where there only has to be tweet messages multiple fields (i.e., information of other rows from col1 to 8) are presented in that one specific cell.

Below are codes that I tried running. It is weird as this problem is not occuring when I am reading this CSV file in python. I just have no clue what is happening. Did anyone encountered similar issue?

```
data <- read.csv("Blacklives.csv", header = F, sep = '\t')

data <- read.csv2("Blacklives.csv", header = F, sep = '\t')

data <- read.delim2("Blacklives.csv", header = F, sep = '\t')

data <- read.delim2("Blacklives.csv", header = F, sep = '\t')
```

So I will try to provide more information to my error. The initial data generated by python looks like this in .csv form. It looks bit weird but data are tab delimited [.csv file from Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vw8g.png). However, when I read this data into R (I read data in R and resaved it to .csv just to show you the rows with problematic cell), some cells (i.e., a cell that should contain a tweet from one person) have this large information in them. See below for the example of information contained in a cell. [.csv file from R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9t6s.png)

Comment: Are you able to copy-paste the first few rows of your data and add it to your question? Otherwise it's tricky for anyone here to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Provide a complete minimal example of your problem. Present also the error message.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I updated my question a bit.

Comment: Can you provide the source .json? it might be a better idea (and also easier) to process directly from there.